# What does regularity property refer to in the context of real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

For example, "regularity properties of Borel measure" as in Rudin's Complex and Real analysis Chapter 2. It seems to be about the approximation of the measure of a set via that of compact subset (inner regularity) and open supset (outer regularity) for that specific section. But what about in general as I've seen in other places?

Comment: Could you please give some examples of you have seen the term "regularity" being used in other places?

Comment: In descriptive set theory one talks of regularity properties of certain sets of reals. Usually one means Lebesgue measurability, the property of Baire and the perfect set property (the set is either countable or contains a perfect subset). Sometimes one includes additional properties (such as the Ramsey property) that are less familiar to analysts. The idea is that having these properties is a way to formalize the intuition that the sets under consideration "are well behaved", and one typically establishes the properties simultaneously for all sets in some classes.

Comment: (Say, all projective sets.) In that case, one may want to establish stronger results (for "reasonable" classes of sets, where "reasonableness" means closure under natural operations such as continuous preimages), such as showing that all sets in the class are determined (meaning that certain infinite games admit winning strategies).